# What is the difference between Yaesu noise blanker (analog IF) and Icom noise blanker (perhaps digital)

Tags: hf, equipment-design, yaesu, icom, noise-blanker

What is the difference between the Yaesu (say FT DX 5000) and Icom (say IC 7700) noise blankers? I understood that the Yaesu NB is an analogue one while Icom uses a digital solution.

Comment: It seems you've already found the difference: The Yaesu noise blanker is analogue, while the Icom is digital.

Comment: Without a specific question about differences besides the ones you already mentioned, I'm voting to close this as unclear. As it stands, it's attracting low-quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with those two rigs but generally speaking from my experience, analog noise blankers are separate analog circuits while the digital rigs integrate digital noise blanking into the existing DSP.

This is kind of an apple vs. orange kind of thing. Some people prefer one ofter the other.

For me, I prefer the warm analog. It seems richer to my ear. Digital has a tendency to be a bit too clean. It almost flattens the audio. The bands are supposed to have some spirt!

Answer (score -2):

In my understanding it has to do with the way we "intervene" on the Intermediate Frequency (IF) of our receivers- which is actually the mixing of the carrier signal with a local oscillator in order to get the difference frequency which holds the actual "information"- which is amplified on the next stage.

So, in the analog option we change the frequency of the oscillator a bit in order to filter out the frequency portion of the carrier that interferes with the portion that has the actual information we prefer to listen to. The IF DSP filtering does exactly the same with digital precision and methods, thus more accurately.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing an IF Shift function here, not a noise blanker.

Comment: You are right Kevin, I am not sure why but my mind went to the IF DSP feature